# solr 1.4.1 solrj client with solr 3.6.2 server?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, solr

I've been trying to work through an issue that developed while attempting to upgrade our testing environment from 12.04 to 14.04 ubuntu on aws. Prior to this, the Package repository version of solr was 1.4.1 which matched our 1.4.1 solrj client integrated with our application.

Changing the base AMI to the 14.04 latest and running our default deploy caused solr 3.6.2 server to be installed. It appears it was accepting our configs without issue, however when our client tried to connect we received different errors:

The first was an unknown custom field, which we traced back to our deployment scripts not moving our schema.xml and solrconfig.xml to /etc/solr/conf/ but keeping it in the base directory.

We corrected this issue, and then ran into the following:
'exception: Invalid version or the data in not in 'javabin' format'

This was generated by a wrapper ontop of solrj, but I'll be honest and say I know nothing regarding Solr and that this may be on our end. I've asked our dev team to look at 2 options:

1) enabling: 'server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());' 
Which is the recommendation on the backwards compatibility for an older client.

2) updating our client in the application to 3.6.2
-I know less about the requirements on this.

My fall back is to revert to 1.4.1, but it appears it hasn't been touched since 2011, which makes me hesitant.

Any thoughts / suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to maintain the same version of Solr and Solrj.

I used for a lot of time Solr 1.4.1 and, while as you said, the most part of it works with newer versions without any problem, actually a lot of things have been changed since 1.4.*

I did your same porting last year, (from 1.4.1 to 3.6.1) and I can confirm you that the 2nd way is the right one: all changes you must do in your client code are just "formal" and very very quick.

Any workaround you could do for being able to communicate with a different version (between Solrj and Solr) is just, as the word says, a "workaround" and it could lead to unexpected (hidden) side-effects later.